# I have created an object but when called ,it says not defined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I watched a tutorial and did the same exact thing. now, this "not defined" error keeps showing I even tried in another browser but the same result. I'm new to JS need help thank you.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

}

  
  var milz = new person("milz", 23);
  var stefi = new person("stefi", 19);

</script>
</head>




<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("hello ");
document.write(stefi.age);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never called `person`, and even if you did, you'd get a recursive overflow, and even if you didn't get an overflow, `stefi` would not be in scope at the top level

Comment: Move var milz = new person("milz", 23); var stefi = new person("stefi", 19); out of the function Person.

Comment: As this question is closed I will update the question so you can get solution

Comment: got it. thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  
  
}
var milz = new person("milz", 23);
  var stefi = new person("stefi", 19);

</script>
</head>




<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("hello ");
document.write(stefi.age);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```